# Latex and multibib

Tags: latex

I want to split my bibliography into two parts, and found the [multibib package](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf) which seems to be perfect for this.
But: somehow it doesn't work, not even the simple example works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{ltex}{\TeX\ and \LaTeX\ References}
\begin{document}
References to the \TeX book \citeltex{Knuth:1991} and to Lamport’s \LaTeX\ book, which appears only in the references\nociteltex{Lamport:1994}. Finally a cite to a Postscript tutorial \cite{Adobe:1985}.
\bibliographystyleltex{alpha}
\bibliographyltex{lit}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Postscript References}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit}
\end{document}
```

With the bib file looking like that

```
@book{Knuth:1991, author = {Knuth, Donald E.}, title = {The TEC book}, publisher = {Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts}, year = {1991}}
@book{Lamport:1994, author = {Lamport, Leslie}, title = {LATEX: A Document Preparation System}, publisher = {Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 2 edition}, year = {1994} }
@book{Adobe:1985, author = {Adobe System Incorporated},   title = {Postscript Language Tutorial and Cookbook},   publisher = {Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts},   year = {1985}}
```

As expected, two aux files are created (one for each part), but the created pdf file only contains the references for the "normal", not for the created bib.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome to post latex questions on Stack Overflow, but be aware that [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) is now operating in public beta and you may get a faster response on that site.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I found it out by myself:

I'm using Texniccenter and tought all the compiling is done automatically, but an additional bibtex call is needed for the ltex.aux file, so you need to run

```
bibtex ltex.aux
```

manually on the command line, then it works.
Perhaps someone knows a way to do that call from Texniccenter?

Answer (score 3):

Open the ltex.aux file in Texnic Center (through File then Open...).
Once it is open and it is the selected tab in Texnic Center, go to Build, Current File... and click Bibtex. The key here is to choose the Bibtex command in the Current File option.
This performs the same as bibtex ltex.aux in Texnic Center